# MVC RouteUrl performance with database lookups in constraints

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Our MVC3 routing engine has a couple entries which have a constraint which involves a database lookup to evaluate.  For example:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Product",
            "{manufacturer}/{partNumber}",
            new { controller = "Product", action = "Details", manufacturer = "" },
            new { manufacturer = new ManufacturerConstraint() }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Store",
            "{store}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Store", action = "Index" },
            new { store = new StoreConstraint() }
        );
```

where `ManufacturererConstraint()` involves a database lookup and `StoreConstraint()` does not.

We're using `RouteUrl` to generate a link similar to:

```
RouteUrl("Product", new { manufacturer = product.Brand, partNumber = product.PartNumber });
```

Three questions from this:

1. Does our usage cause a database lookup?
2. If I generated a route for the "Store" route, would that also generate a lookup as it tests it against all routes?  Or would it only do the one test for the specified route?
3. If it does hit the database in this usage, is there a way to use `RouteUrl` that wouldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does our usage cause a database lookup?

Yes, if the constraint is setup to work on UrlGeneration. `Url.RouteUrl` runs all constraints, just like `Url.Action`. The only difference is that you are explicitly saying which route you would like to use, instead of testing each route until one matches.

> If I generated a route for the "Store" route, would that also generate
>   a lookup as it tests it against all routes? Or would it only do the
>   one test for the specified route?

I think I answered this above.

> If it does hit the database in this usage, is there a way to use
>   RouteUrl that wouldn't?

Setup the constraint so it doesn't run on UrlGeneration (using the `routeDirection` parameter). Personally, I'd cache the lookup data instead.

Comment: So in the constraint, only hit the database if `routeDirection == RouteDirection.IncomingRequest`?  I've thought of caching the data, but it could theoretically change at any time - for example, a new brand could be added on the spot to show to a representative, or we might have to pull one down ASAP.   If there's a way to cache it in such a way that we can invalidate and reload it as necessary, I'd certainly look into that.

Comment: Why do you need to check the database on URL generation? If you get a partNumber from the database you already know it's valid. For incoming request, it's common to do that check in the action method and return 404 if it doesn't exist.

Comment: On generation, we don't.  But until this answer I didn't know it was possible not to.  The problem with doing it for incoming requests is that we have several routes which *could* match a given URL, depending on whether the first thing is a brand or the name of a store (or several other things).  So either we have one giant action which handles all the parsing then returns the correct controller action, or we check each one.